# What is meant by clustering in database or a cluster in Database?

Tags: mysql, oracle10g

What is meant by clustering in database or a cluster in Database?Eventhough when I am googling it several definitions are there which I can not understand.Can any one tell me in a simple way?I am new to database concept.

Comment: Clustering can mean many things, depending on context, as it is a synonim of grouping. It can be anything from using a group by, to creating a network of databases to act as one(a cluster)

Answer (score 1):

A cluster is a schema object that contains data from one or more tables. Among all the tables one or more columns are common.

Answer (score 0):

In Database or Data mining Clustering is a grouping the data. It is comes under aggregation in DBMS. We clustering the data by some common fields in a table.

Answer (score 0):

A new Typer of of MariaDB Cluster is Galera Cluster. There a 3 or more Nodes (Database Server) in the Cluster and each hold the complete Data and you can use each for read or write (Multi Master)

- Synchronous replication
- Active-active multi-master topology
- Read and write to any cluster node
- Automatic membership control, failed nodes drop from the cluster
- Automatic node joining
- True parallel replication, on row level
- Direct client connections, native MySQL look & feel

[MariaDB Galera Cluster]